# How to know how much memory our object uses?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I know that int uses 32 bits. Long uses 64 bits and etc... But, how can we know how much memory our object uses? I have a class like this:

```
class Utils{
   public String getName(Context context){
      return "Sambhav"
   }
}
```

Now, how can I know how much memory does this class use?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  You don't have an object.  You have a static method that returns a `String`.   The amount of memory occupied by the code of the `Utils` class is not possible to determine (unless you are prepared to do a huge amount of research and "bookkeeping"), and it is probably irrelevant.

Comment: Why do you need to know how much memory an instance of this will take ?. In any case, it will depend on the runtime environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't. You can only do some very rough estimates. It depends on the version of your JRE.

- Every instance has a minimum memory footprint for management information like a reference to the defining class, maybe 16 bytes.
- For every instance field, add the "size" of that field, plus some padding if the field type is shorter than the default alignment used in your JRE.
- A class is an instance of the class named `Class`, having a lot of internal fields and data structures, besides the fields declared `static`. And it "holds" the bytecode of the methods defined there and any compiled native method versions from the HotSpot Just-In-Time compiler. So it's close to impossible to estimate the memory consumption of adding a new class to a JRE.
- A string literal like `"Sambhav"` adds one `String` instance to the constants pool if it isn't already present there. And a `String` instance has at least a length field and an array holding the characters. The internal details have changed with various versions of JRE.

Now analyzing your `Utils` class snippet:

- You only have the class, no instance. So, add the (unknown) memory footprint of the class to your calculation.
- Your user code needs one `String` literal that's probably not yet present in the constant pool. So, add two instances to your calculation, one `String` instance plus one character-holding array, with the array's footprint of course depending on the string length.